# Bytebuffer output Android Java

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

i want to display the first 4 characters of my dummy data. 
How do i do that?
I want as output :

```
outputvalue = $*
outputvalue = 22



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    byte[] outData = ("$*220000000000101SDFRGGHYB0").getBytes();
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(outData);
    System.out.println("The structure"+ b);
    outputvalue1 = $*
    outputvalue2 = 22



}
```

Comment: The problem here: what kind of strings are you talking about? You understand that Characters in Java represent Unicode. There is no guarantee that your "first 2 chars" fit into 4 bytes?!

Comment: Are you wanting the output "$*22"?

Comment: no i want 1 output value $* and 1 output value 22

Comment: And why do you expect the `short` (16-bit integer) you created with the first two bytes of your char array to print as `"$*"`? You deliberately turned it into an integer, when you want to see a string. Did you actually want to use a `CharBuffer`, have it produce a `String`, and then print two different `String.substring()`s, or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] outData = "$*220000000000101SDFRGGHYB0".getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(outData);

byte[] outputValue1 = new byte[2];
b.get(outputValue1);

byte[] outputValue2 = new byte[2];
b.get(outputValue2);

String outputString1 = new String(outputValue1, "UTF-8");
String outputString2 = new String(outputValue2, "UTF-8");
int outputNum2 = Integer.parseInt(outputString2);
```

String is always in Unicode, and binary data (byte[]) as text have some encoding, charset. This must be mentioned when converting between `String/Reader/Writer` and `byte[]/InputStream/OutputStream`

[ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) allows positioned, random access reading and writing. The above uses linear reading.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps mine problem